# Type annotations for parameters and variables in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio, class, types, annotations

I am using VS2015 with the Python tools. In order to use IntelliSense I want to annotate function parameters and variables with the type that is stored in it.

Can I do this? Via some kind of annotation?

Comment: Maybe `docstring`?

Comment: How would that look like. I know docstring. but how would I annotate a variable with it and give its type?